# Bold cell value from row copy to another cell in same row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some rows with different values in cells.

What I want to do is, when a value gets bold, just copy that value in another cell.

If this is not possible maybe mark it somehow, I want to avoid ctrl + c / ctrl + v

Do you guys have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: To do it by Bold you will need vba and SuperUser is not a code for me site.

Comment: @ScottCraner , who said something about code for me? I just need some leads, I'm not a excel user, thats why I ask. But I guess that's how a comment looks, when you have nothing to say. You should try the downvote as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I created an ActiveX button ( http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/activex-controls.html ) with the following code:

```
Dim value As Double
Dim column As Integer
column = 3 - ActiveCell.column
value = ActiveCell.value
ActiveCell(1, column).value = value
```

Also you can make the button sticky with "Freeze Panes" from "View" tab

P.S. I'm sure there are easier and more pragmatic ways to do this.